# is there a way to change scrolbar style in delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, delphi-2010

I just noticed while building a delphi 2010 application that the scrollbar is always the same size when it shows up. The scroller in the middle of the bar is always the same size no matter how much there actually is to scroll. In contrast, most modern applications use scrollbars where the size of the scroller is proportional to the amount available to scroll, so that by looking it is clear how much there is to scroll through. Is there a way to change the scroll properties on my delphi controls, or would that require custom controls?

edit:
The component in this particular instance was a TDBGrid, which scrolled horizontally. I didn't realize that windows was drawing these scrollbars. Perhaps Warren is correct and the question is unanswerable. Proportional scrollbars may not be ubiquitous on windows but I have yet to find a program on my windows machine that doesn't use them. Even the delphi 2010 IDE uses them.

Comment: More detail please. What control is your scroll bar attached to?

Comment: Windows Common controls (Memo, RichEdit, Listbox and many others) draw their own scrollbars, so it's incorrect to say Delphi 2010 has anything to do with it. Even most custom controls in Delphi (if not all of them) delegate 100% of scrollbar painting to Windows itself.  I have not observed any control that ships in Delphi 2010 having a fixed small scrollbar thumb size.

Comment: Proportional scrollbars aren't as common (or as easy) as you think. Raymond Chen (MSFT) explains here, and perhaps this will help: [Scrollbars, part 4: Adding a proportional scrollbar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/31/54601.aspx)

Comment: I voted to close because the OP has not edited the question in 14 hours, and has not updated with any additional detail. I believe this question is unanswerable.  Select scrollbar style on a specific control, with a code example and a picture of what you want to do, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it in a custom component of mine (a simple text viewer):

```
procedure TCustomViewer.UpdateScrollInfo;
var
  ScrollInfo: TScrollInfo;
begin
  with ScrollInfo do
  begin
    cbSize := SizeOf(ScrollInfo);
    fMask := SIF_POS or SIF_PAGE or SIF_RANGE or SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
    nMin := 0;
    nMax := 1023;
    nPage := PageWidth;
    nPos := FTopLeft.X;
  end;
  SetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_HORZ, ScrollInfo, True);
  with ScrollInfo do
  begin
    nMax := FLines.Count - 1;
    nPage := PageHeight;
    nPos := FTopLeft.Y;
  end;
  SetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, ScrollInfo, True);
  UpdateCaretPos;
  Update;
end;
```

IOW, you use a `TScrollInfo`, fill it up with the values you need to change, including `nMax` and `nPage`, and call `SetScrollInfo` with it, indicating the scroll bar you want to change. I'm sure that most controls with scroll bars control them internally, but if a control doesn't, you could try `SetScrollInfo`. It might work for some of them. `TScrollInfo` and `SetScrollInfo` are defined in `Windows.pas`. Here is [the MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: FWIW, this is very old code (but I tried it and it still works), and those days, I had no reservations on the use of `with`. ;-)

Comment: -1 I'm afraid I think this code is misleading. The `TScrollBar.PageSize` property is what should be used to achieve this and it has been available in Delphi since Delphi 5 and almost certainly before.

Comment: Since OP is interested in `TDBGrid`, it seems you are right that there is nothing like `ThumbSize` or `PageSize` built into the VCL.